# Why can't I initialize a Rails 4 model, with NoMethodError: undefined method `custom_text='

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 model with some attributes. Unfortunately I cannot initialize it, for the attribute doesn't get set.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: my_model
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  custom_text :text
#  ...etc...

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def initialize(new_text)
    self.custom_text = new_text
  end

end

# MyModel.new("ok")
# Produces the following error:
undefined method `custom_text=' for #<MyModel not initialized>
```

Why can't I initialize the model, getting instead NoMethodError: undefined method `custom_text='?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't created an attribute accessor for custom_text, therefore there is no function named 'custom_text='

But you don't need to override initialize here at all.  Just instantiate your model object by calling new and passing a hash with whatever attributes you want to set:

```
mm = MyModel.new(custom_text: "ok")
```

ActiveRecord::Base provides an initializer that does most of the heavy lifting for you.  There are very few circumstances where you'd need to override it.